# Is there a way to assign a lattice to the demensions of an objects bounding box? Blender 2.8

Tags: modeling, python

I'm curious if, with a script, I could click a button and with the object I have selected have a lattice that is the dimensions of the objects bounding box? I have my own panel of scripts that I have made to cut down on simple but time consuming tasks and this would be perfect I'm just not sure how I would go about this.

Comment: Have you done any research on the topic? I get a lot of links by searching "blender script lattice".

Comment: Yeah I have looked at some scripts but almost all of them I have seen have you add it in edit mode to selected vertices. What I'm looking to do is have it applied to the dimensions of the bounding box or something similar to where a lattice is quickly placed around the entire object.

Comment: are you using google or duckduckgo? This is the first result I get https://blendermarket.com/products/fit-lattice?ref=2

Comment: Consider trying `D.objects['Lattice'].dimensions = C.object.dimensions` in python console. Sets the dimensions of the lattice object named "Lattice" to those of the context object.